# Twitter Bootstrap input fields

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms the following code gives nicely styled input field with button attached to each other.

```
<div class="input-append">
  <input class="span2" id="appendedInputButton" type="text">
  <button class="btn" type="button">Go!</button>
</div>
```

My question is how would I have two input fields next to each other before the button with the same styling (no double borders in between)

I tried doing

```
<div class="input-append">
  <input class="span2" id="appendedInputButton" type="text">
  <input class="span2" id="appendedInputButton" type="text">
  <button class="btn" type="button">Go!</button>
</div>
```

but the styling broke.

Comment: What do you mean by "double borders"? What do you mean by "the styling broke"?

Comment: @Grigor imho, it's not a constructive way to reply..if someone has a doubt and is enquiring about your post then you ought to give respect and state the clarification as sought..

Comment: @Grigor I was merely trying to clarify the problem you were having and the result you were trying to achieve. Comments like "but it broke" and "but it won't work" are unclear and make questions difficult to answer with any certainty.

Comment: my sincere apologies @RossHamish. I hope you don't feel bad from my comment (I deleted it already) I was frustrated

Answer (score 0):

i hope the below code will help..

```css
#appendedInputButton2{
  border-left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-append">
  <input class="span2" id="appendedInputButton1" type="text">
  <input class="span2" id="appendedInputButton2" type="text">
  <button class="btn" type="button">Go!</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap, button-group is the thing you are looking for:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Right</button>
</div>
```